# TLS issue while calling stripe charge API from my local env

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am implementing Stripe payment gateway in sandbox mode. I have embedded checkout process and also created token which is used by server to call API to create charges.

API version used is: `stripe.api_version = '2017-06-05'`

```
charge = stripe.Charge.create(
   amount=1000,
   currency="usd",
   description="Example charge",
   source=token,
)
```

When I call this charge create api, I receive the following error:

> b'{\n  "error": {\n    "type": "invalid_request_error",\n
>   "message": "Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0.
>   Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later. You can learn
>   more about this at https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls."\n  }\n}\n'

The stripe API used to create charges in local machine is:

```
POST: https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges
```

How can I make it work on my local machine?

But when I deployed it to AWS it is working there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your local Python interpreter is linked against an older version of OpenSSL that does not support TLS 1.2. You can check this with:

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
```

You need OpenSSL 1.0.1 or more recent to use TLS 1.2.

If you're using OS X, the simplest way to fix this is to the use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade && brew install openssl && brew install python
```

Replace `python` with `python3` at the end of the command line above if you're using Python 3.

Comment: When I run `$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"` initially, it gave me `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`. But after running `$ brew update && brew upgrade && brew install openssl && brew install python3` it gives me `openssl 1.0.2n`. But in my project's virtual environment the version does not get changed.It says `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016` inside virtual environment

Comment: @AnkitaGupta This means your virtualenv is still using OS X's default Python (`/usr/bin/python`) instead of the one installed by brew (`/usr/local/bin/python3`).